# Access form: trapping date changes in textbox

Tags: vba, events, ms-access, ms-access-2010

On a normal textbox, I usually use the `AfterUpdate` event to perform some action. That means the user has to press *Enter* or *Tab* after typing, or click in another control, and I have always been happy with that behaviour.
Now  I am setting up a Date filter in the header of a continuous form in Access 2010, and I realize that changing the date through the little calendar that comes automatically, does NOT fire the `AfterUpdate` event, forcing to press Enter after selecting the correct date, which is a bit heavy.
Using `OnChange` would trigger at every character entered, which is not nice either.
Any suggestion ?

Comment: If you use the little calendar, the On Change event will only fire once, and what is the betting that that is what people will do?

Comment: @Remou: right, but I'd like to leave them the option of typing the date. I tried to use OnChange + checking the number of characters and IsDate(), but that produces messy results...and I don't want to spend half a day on that. The ideal would be to have the "little calendar" firing an event.

Comment: I cannot see any way that the little calendar will give you an event, however, the keypress event will only happen when the user types in the control, so with a module level variable, a keypress and a change event, you might just get close.

Answer (score 2):

It is a bit late reply but I hope it will help the others.
When using textbox as a DatePicker you should use Change Event with your filter.

However when you are checking your textbox like `Form_name.TextboxName` it will show last picked date. To avoid that and use currently selected one you need to provide current date like `Form_name.TextboxName.Text`. Careful here because `.Text` property is sensitive to focus.

...in short:

`Form_name.TextboxName` - will show last picked date
`Form_name.TextboxName.Text` - will show currently picked date

Answer (score 1):

well, after you select a date from the date-picker, the Change event occurs for the TextBox control. Then, call a sub or function or set focus to another control... to avoid event fires for each pressed key, put something like:
if Len(me.activecontrol) < 10 then exit sub

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I use LostFocus event in the textbox. It allows to use the calendar tool and alter the content. The User has to leave the textbox sooner or later, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I use it in this way

```
Private Sub txt_FirstDate_Change()
    txt_FirstDate = txt_FirstDate.Text
    myfilter
End Sub
```